# OpenMP: Replace critical section with locks

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, locking, openmp, critical-section

How can I replace a critical section with omp_locks instead?

My original code with critical section is like this, which works fine:

```
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // do thread-safe pre-processing

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        // do critical section stuff
    }
}
```

Now I do the same thing but with locks instead:

```
omp_lock_t lock;
omp_init_lock(&lock);

#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // do thread-safe pre-processing

    omp_set_lock(&lock);

    // do critical section stuff

    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}
omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
```

But for some reason, I get the wrong result. Am I doing something wrong here?

Also, when I try to use multiple locks (e.g. for each element of array to write on), it seems to go into deadlock?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `omp parallel` in that?

Comment: Ah the whole thing is inside a `#pragma omp parallel` block

Comment: @Gyakenji Maybe put the lock initialisation outside of the parallel block?

Comment: The whole thing? Including the definition of the lock variable? Yeah, that'd be a problem because that makes them private ones, not shared...

Comment: @Shawn Ahh yes, that makes sense. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use lock in OpenMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396430/how-to-use-lock-in-openmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careless mistake: defining lock should be outside parallel block