# How to create an array of pointers with lock and check the pointer free or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have an array pointers.

Can I use mutex for lock and unlock? At the same time, Another thread run with the same and check matrix[h].

```
int **matrix;
matrix =new int[20];
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
  matrix[i]= new int[20];
}

#pragma omp parallel for nowait
for(int h=0; h< 20; ++h)
{
   if(matrix[h].isfree()==true)
   {
     lock(matrix[h]);
     //do something...
     unlock(matrix[h]);
   }
   else
   {
     //that array matrix[h] is not free. 
     skip++;
   }
}
```

Comment: You must provide more information about *"do something"*, otherwise we cannot actually properly answer the question! `matrix[h].isfree()` also makes no sense for an `int*`. Please create a [mcve], the current answers may mislead you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is never to block the thread it suffices to use `std::atomic_bool` .
Otherwise you should use `std::lock_guard` in combination with `std::mutex` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `omp_lock_t mylock;` for declaring the lock instead of `pthread_mutex_t mylock;` as you are using openmp. Then you can initialize the lock and use `omp_set_lock(&mylock);` to put a lock and `omp_unset_lock(&mylock);` to remove the lock. Have a look at this -> 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/2396430/how-to-use-lock-in-openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396430/how-to-use-lock-in-openmp)